# How does rails manage associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm still learning Ruby, and get caught up in alot of the 'magic', wanting to better understand what is actually happening, and making sure that I understand what it is doing.

I've got a user, and each user has entries. 
In my user class, I have

```
has_many :entries
```

and in my entries class I have

```
belongs_to :user
```

I was expecting that the entries table would have a column for users, but I'm not seeing that when I 'describe' the database.

How do I know, or how does Rails know which user the entry is connected to? Or do I need to create a field myself to do that?

It seems strange to me that we have all these 'belongs_to', etc. yet it isn't explicit how that connection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception. Associations do not create the database tables for you. Instead, you have to create them yourself. What you need to be careful of, is that an Entry model would have a user_id field, in order for the association to fully work. I truly would not want to advertise or anything, but i have created a blog post that can help you quite a lot i think :

http://www.codercaste.com/2011/02/06/rails-association-in-plain-english-what-i-wish-i-had-known-before-i-started/

Comment: Thanks SpyrosP, your post does a decent job of explaining the different types of associations, but I'm still trying to figure out how to create the associations in the database. What is the best way to do that? I would think it would be un-rails-like to pass an id to a form in a hidden field, but I'm not sure.

In this instance, I can get the user from current_user, but if later I want to add in another class like entry_votes, I'm trying to figure out the rails way of linking these things.

Comment: I understand you so much, i had the same questions when started :) For the associations, once you create them, you can do something like user.entries. Rails is responsible for doing the underlying joins for you. So, your assocs above are correct. Then create the db tables, without forgetting to add user_id as an attribute to your entries model. Rails actually passes hidden stuff on its own :P Ids and forms is actually a different topic. I would strongly suggest that you take a look here as well : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and also take a look at how rails is routing.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was 'hidden stuff' being passed due to the associations in the models, but couldn't find any documentation on that sort of thing. You've been a great help.